# JPQL - Predicate and criteriaAPI

Tags: jpa, jpql, predicate

I'd like to write a Predicate which is calculated based on 2 columns. 
for example - I have a daysBetween (int) and lastSent (date).

I'd like to know if there's a possibility to perform the following query :

select from X where the last_sent + [some other column which is interval] lessThan now()

something similar to (and I now this is not the correct way to write it..),

```
builder.between(userData.<Date>get("lastSent").addDays(userIntervals.<Integer>get("interval")),DateUtils.now());
```

Is there anyway of writing such a query using predicates?

Answer (score 0):

JPA Criteria does not define an addDays() API.  You can call a database specific function through the function() API,

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Special_Operations

Some JPA providers provide extensions to JPQL and Criteria.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#JpaCriteriaBuilder_and_EclipseLink_Extensions

and,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#EclipseLink_Extensions_.28EQL.29